When did Batman first break his "never hit a lady" rule in the comics?
I was reading Batman Vol. 1 #409 (1987), when I came across something interesting that got me wondering about Batman's history with female opponents.
There's this scene where Batman breaks up a heist at the Gotham Art Museum led by Faye "Ma" Gunn. During the fight, Ma Gunn taunts Batman with "You wouldn't hit a lady," and he replies, "Never." A panel shows his fist in front of her chin, but it's kind of unclear what actually happened, though we do see her knocked out on the floor right after.

This interaction appears to be a deliberate nod to the "Wouldn't Hit a Girl" trope—something that seems particularly significant for a character like Batman, who's known for his strict moral code.
I've definitely seen Batman fight and hit women before, especially in animated shows, but I'm not as familiar with the comics. It got me wondering—what was the first instance of Batman hitting a female opponent in comic history?

Not sure what's unclear -- it looks like he knocks her out cold (BIFF!). I guess he doesn't consider her a lady.

Well, it's certainly not unmistakable: why the weird coloured space between Bats' fist and her chin? The "never" could also imply he doesn't break this rule here. Is he using a shock wave to knock her down?

@Bossie The panel's actually a bit ambiguous since we don't see the punch connect. But given how she ends up, I'd say you're probably right.

This page doesn't necessarily suggest it’s an actual rule of his.  The ‘never’ seemed just to be a sarcastic answer to her attempt to avoid getting hit.

@Joachim That yellow space makes it unclear to me. I can't really tell if Batman follows through with the punch or holds back, which might be intentional on the artist's part.

@suchiuomizu You're probably right about him being sarcastic there. Either way, I'm more interested in finding out when Batman first hit a female opponent in comic history.

In the very first Batman issue back in 1940 he threatens to "spank" Catwoman, but as far as I can tell he never actually hits her. So at the very least we know he's been willing to make exceptions to the rule right from the word "go".

It made a sound!  Batman must have hit her, unless he can summon the BIFF! sound effect at will.

Seems like a play on a "lady" being the feminine form a "gentleman." He's simultaneously knocking her out and calling her un-genteel.

@NathanK. "BIFF" is an odd sound for a punch landing. To me, it sounds more like his fist slicing through the air but not actually connecting.

Although it's fallen out of use nowadays, "BIFF!" was one of various sound effects (along with "SOCK!", "POW!", and more besides) classically used to signify a punch landing in older works, such as the 1960s Batman TV show (there are examples of it at the 0:29, 1:36, 5:49 and 6:06 marks in this video). My understanding of comicbook vernacular is telling me that Batman definitely punched that woman in the image in your question, but it was probably with a fraction of his full strength; little more than a tap on the chin from his perspective.

@LogicDictates I see. Poor Ma Gunn - even a "gentle" tap from Batman's fist can't feel too great.

Based on past form, he probably wouldn't have hit her if she was genuinely surrendering, but an astute observer like him would surely have noticed that she was hiding something behind her back, guessed that it was a weapon, and calculated that he should incapacitate her immediately rather than taking any chances.

Trivia: Batman is an equal opportunity crime fighter

He slaps Catwoman in Batman Vol. 1 #10 (May, 1942).


Batman Vol. 1 #10 (May, 1942)

He karate chops an unusually strong woman in Batman Family Vol. 1 #17 (May, 1978), noting that he doesn't like the idea of striking a woman, but has no choice in this instance. The identity of this woman is unclear. Another character calls her 'Millie,' and upon first sighting her from a distance, Batman initially thinks she's Margo Mulhare, a missing actress he was searching for, but changes his mind when he sees her up close.

BATMAN: She's trying to kill me--and her fear or rage has made her--abnormally strong! I don't like the idea of striking a woman--but she leaves me no choice!

Batman Family Vol. 1 #17 (May, 1978)

He punches Selina Kyle/Catwoman in Batman Vol 1 #404 (February, 1987). This occurs during the "Batman: Year One" storyline, shortly before either Bruce Wayne or Selina had adopted their costumed identities.


Batman Vol. 1 #404 (February, 1987)

There are quite a few examples of him punching or kicking female opponents from the 1980s onwards; his fights with the martial artist, Lady Shiva, for instance, the first one occurring in Batman Vol. 1 #427 (December, 1988). Examples from before the '80s seem to be much rarer. In most of his early encounters with Catwoman and Poison Ivy, they either get away or he finds ways to capture them without actually striking them.

He wrestles a witch in Batman Vol 1 #6. I think that's the first time we see him laying hands on a woman, although he doesn't seem to actually hit her.

As videos of slap contests show, slaps can be quite powerful.  They're a part of multiple martial arts, including sumo.  The line Batman speaks there also implies he's attempting to knock Catwoman out - at that point, the difference between a slap and a punch is just what part of the hand you're hitting somebody with.

@Clockwork-Muse - The slap apparently didn't knock Catwoman out, since she was barking orders at her goons in the following panel. Also, while slaps can be forceful, when American superheroes like Batman, Spider-Man and Superman use them, it's usually an indication that they're holding back. This doesn't apply to palm thrusts or knifehand strikes, such as those used by Shang-Chi and Iron Fist, which I don't count as slaps.

I think you're misunderstanding the joke, which is that he "wouldn't hit a lady." Batman responding no, and socking her is his way of saying she might be a woman, but she's not comporting herself as a lady.
This is a fairly common joke format. See, for example:

So Batman probably never had a hard and fast "rule" to break against hitting woman, the way he (eventually) had against guns, or killing.
Going off a limb, I would say that you're never going to find an example of Batman hitting a "lady," but plenty of examples of him clocking femme fatales and other devilish rogues. Because the hammer of justice is unisex:


You're likely right about the joke/wordplay with "lady" versus "woman." But I'm actually more interested in your last point—you mentioned there are plenty of examples of Batman hitting female villains. Any idea which comic shows the earliest instance?

While I agree that this is an example of the trope you've mentioned, older Batman stories in particular did suggest that he was less comfortable striking women than men, and preferred to avoid it for the most part. This seems to be less the case from the '80s onwards.

The phrase is going out on a limb. As in walking to the edge of a branch of a tree.

Rather uncomfortable with the second-last image in this post. Was this from some episode where the villain was based on offensive stereotypes about crossdressers/trans people?

@AJM It seems to be an episode from "Batman: The Brave and the Bold (2008-2011)". Never seen that episode though. Edit: Apparently it's in episode "Night of the huntress"

https://braveandbold.fandom.com/wiki/Mrs._Manface

From what little I'm reading, that show is supposed to be an homage to the silver age Batman or something like that, when he was mostly fighting very silly villains. And so Mrs. Manface is just that, a woman who seemingly have masculine features.
